# Hide Angular 2 material tooltip like ngIf

Tags: angular, tooltip, angular-material2

In Angular 1 Material I could use a directive, right now it is an attribute, right now it is very hard to do. How can I do it simply to only show the tooltip like when the width of page is small and hide when it is big?

I cannot find. It is not possibly to use like:

```
<md-tooltip ngIf="false">sometimes hidden</md-tooltip>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly you want to show tooltip only when a certain condition is met, try this:

```
<div [matTooltip]="isWide ? 'Visible' : null"></div>
```

Comment: Actual for Angular 5, just need to replace mdTooltip to matTooltip

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```html
<button
  mat-raised-button
  color="primary"
  [matTooltip]="test ? 'You must complete all the required fields.' : null"
  matTooltipPosition="above"
>
  Primary
</button>
```

If you want to show the tooltip when it's false, just replace `null` with your text.

Answer (score 5):

I made the following directive which shows the tooltip only when the text is larger than the containing element.

I have extened the MatTooltip class to create my own custom directive.

This directive listens for the mouse enter event on the element to which it is attached. It then enables the tooltip only if the size of text exceeds the size of the element.

```html
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Inject, Input, NgZone, Optional, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY,
    MatTooltip,
    MatTooltipDefaultOptions
} from '@angular/material';
import { AriaDescriber, FocusMonitor } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { Directionality } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { Overlay, ScrollDispatcher } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appToolTip]'
})



export class ToolTipDirective extends MatTooltip {

  @Input()
  get appToolTip() {
      return this.message;
  }
  set appToolTip(txt: string) {
    this.message = txt;
  }


  constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    _overlay: Overlay,
    _scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
    _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    _ngZone: NgZone,
    _platform: Platform,
    _ariaDescriber: AriaDescriber,
    _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    @Inject(MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY) _scrollStrategy: any,
    @Optional() _dir: Directionality,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS)
    _defaultOptions: MatTooltipDefaultOptions
    ) {

      super(
      _overlay,
       el,
      _scrollDispatcher,
      _viewContainerRef,
      _ngZone,
      _platform,
      _ariaDescriber,
      _focusMonitor,
      _scrollStrategy,
      _dir,
      _defaultOptions
  );
}

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  check(): void {
    this.disabled = (this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth < this.el.nativeElement.scrollWidth) ?  false :  true;
  }

}
```

Just attach the directive to the element like :

```
<td [appToolTip] = "someTxtString"> {{someTxtString}} </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

`matTooltipDisabled` is used to disable tooltips in Angular. Using this we can conditionally show the tooltip.

```
 <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Disable tooltip" matTooltipDisabled="true">
    Disable tooltip
 </button>
```

We can dynamically change the `[matTooltipDisabled]` input property by binding to a variable.

```
 <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Disable tooltip [matTooltipDisabled]="isDisabled">
    Disable tooltip
 </button>
```

If you want to change the color and other css property of the tooltip,

```
<button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Adding a custom class to the tooltip" matTooltipClass="mat-tooltip">
    Custom tooltip
</button>
```

css file is as below

```
 ::ng-deep   .mat-tooltip{
    color: #3E474B !important;
    background-color:#FCFCFC !important;
    border-color: rgb(197, 197, 197);
    font-size: 14px !important;
  }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in Angular 15. The top two answers didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to conditionally hide an element you can use *ngIf or hidden. Example

```
<div *ngIf="someVariable">content</div>   // if someVariable if true, will display

<div [hidden]="someVariable">content</div>   // if someVariable is true, will hide
```

Comment: sorry for helping. i just need for md-tooltip, which is an attribute. to keep the text, but hide the tooltip, weird.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You want the content to appear outside of the tooltip? In that case just throw it in a separate div with an opposite ngIf condition