# Angular material tooltip display on boolean

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to add a `matTooltip` to the `matInput` field, which will be displayed or not only based on the boolean in the controller, without displaying on hover.

If true - display tooltip and stay like this, else hide tooltip.

Boolean changes based on the directive with event emitter and caps lock key.

```
<input
    matInput
    matTooltip="Caps lock is on!"
    matTooltipPosition="right"
    type="password"
    formControlName="password"
    (keydown.enter)="onSubmit()"
>
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Have you found this SO entry yet? Sounds like your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470225/hide-angular-2-material-tooltip-like-ngif

Comment: For this use case, I recommend using a badge: https://material.angular.io/components/badge/overview

Comment: @AldinBradaric Yes, I saw this thread but it didn't help me, I need the tooltip to be constantly visible without hovering over if boolean is true

Comment: @Faisal I did not even think about such a solution, thank you for the hint, I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try to use "matTooltipDisabled".

```
<input
    matInput
    matTooltip="Caps lock is on!"
    matTooltipPosition="right"
    [matTooltipDisabled]="YOUR_CONDITION"
    type="password"
    formControlName="password"
    (keydown.enter)="onSubmit()"
>
```

I hope this help you, regards.

Comment: Yes, this solution also works when it comes to disabling the tooltip, but for me the most important thing is that this tooltip is always visible when boolean is true, without hovering over the input.